# creating and outputting xml

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); // new dom object
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE; //tidy the output
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('PaymentNotificationResponse'));
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 
        $xml_pay = $sxe->addChild('Payments');
        $paymnt = $xml_pay->addChild('Payment');
        $paymnt->addChild('PaymentLogId','123');
        $paymnt->addChild('Status', '0');
print_r($sxe);
```

This is supposed to print something like this:

```
<PaymentNotificationResponse>
 <Payments>
  <Payment>
   <PaymentLogId>123</PaymentLogId>
   <Status>0</Status>
  </Payment>
 </Payments>
</PaymentNotificationResponse>
```

But what i get is this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Payments] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Payment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PaymentLogId] => 123 [Status] => 0 ) ) )
```

Even when i use

```
print_r($sxe->asXML())
```

it just gives

1230

Comment: what about `echo $sxe->asXML()`?

Comment: If you are seeing 1230 it is because the XML was correctly output, but your browser confused it for HTML because you didn't output the correct header. Look at the browser's _page source_. You'll find the full XML there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Beat you in split of a second. But yeah, I suspect that too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing:

```
echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Should do the trick.

Notice that unless you have the right headers, the browser might read it as HTML. You then have to inspect the source to see the actual XML.

Answer (score 0):

To print the correct output you should print $sxe->asXML(), but if you want to have the output shown in the XML format on the browser you should also print the header in php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8')
```

for the sake of the example check the code bellow:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); // new dom object
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE; //tidy the output
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('PaymentNotificationResponse'));
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 
        $xml_pay = $sxe->addChild('Payments');
        $paymnt = $xml_pay->addChild('Payment');
        $paymnt->addChild('PaymentLogId','123');
        $paymnt->addChild('Status', '0');
print_r( header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8') . $sxe->asXML());
```